# How can I solve this memory leak in iOS App?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments

After analyzing my application with Instruments, the tool tells me I have memory leaks but I do not see why that message if I think I am releasing memory correctly. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: This looks like the time profiler, not leaks instrument.

Comment: It's Leaks Instruments.

Comment: it may come from the enqueue method

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that syncTask is not retained in **enqueue:** method.

And one more possibility may be if you implement any delegate in TaskQueue make sure your are using **assign** not strong or retain in property.